# Choosing vectors for projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, algorithms, discrete-optimization

I have a vector $v = a_1\mu_1 + a_2\mu_2 + ... + a_n\mu_n$ where $\mu_i$ are given linearly independent but not orthogonal vectors.

I need to choose  $k$ vectors from the original set such that when I project $v$ onto the space spanned by these vectors, the length of the projection is highest possible.

Are there any algorithms that could solve this problem?  $n$ is very large number.

Comment: Can these $k$ vectors be linear combinations of $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$? If so, you can use SVD, and select the vectors corresponding to the largest $k$ sigular value.

Comment: @Ryan, no they can't. only $\mu_i$ themselves

Comment: Sorry, I also realized that we cannot use the linear combinations since you only have a vector (the projection would be $v$ itself in that case). I think the SVD may be helpful, as it gives an ordered significance, but I am not sure.

Comment: I assume k is some fixed number less than n, then how big is k compared to n?

Comment: @amitava $k$ is very small compared to $n$